# Index on subpartition on Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, database-partitioning

I have created a composite Range-List partition on a table which follows the following sample code.

```
CREATE TABLE sample_regional_sales
      (deptno number, item_no varchar2(20),
       txn_date date, txn_amount number, state varchar2(2))
  PARTITION BY RANGE (txn_date)
    SUBPARTITION BY LIST (state)
      (PARTITION q1_1999 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-APR-1999','DD-MON-YYYY'))
          TABLESPACE tbs_1
         (SUBPARTITION q1_1999_northwest VALUES ('OR', 'WA'),
          SUBPARTITION q1_others VALUES (DEFAULT) TABLESPACE tbs_4
         ),
       PARTITION q2_1999 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('1-JUL-1999','DD-MON-YYYY'))
          TABLESPACE tbs_2
         (SUBPARTITION q2_1999_northwest VALUES ('OR', 'WA'),
          SUBPARTITION q2_1999_southcentral VALUES ('OK', 'TX')
         ),
       PARTITION q3_1999 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-OCT-1999','DD-MON-YYYY'))
          TABLESPACE tbs_3
         (SUBPARTITION q3_1999_northwest VALUES ('OR', 'WA'),
          SUBPARTITION q3_others VALUES (DEFAULT) TABLESPACE tbs_4
         ),
       PARTITION q4_1999 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('1-JAN-2000','DD-MON-YYYY'))
          TABLESPACE tbs_4
      );
```

I was able to create an index on the range partition:

```
create index SOME_INDEX_NAME on sample_regional_sales (txn_date) global
    PARTITION by range (txn_date)
    (
    PARTITION q1_1999 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-APR-1999','DD-MON-YYYY')),
    PARTITION q2_1999 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-JUL-1999','DD-MON-YYYY')),
    PARTITION q3_1999 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-OCT-1999','DD-MON-YYYY')),
    PARTITION q3_1999 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-NOV-1999','DD-MON-YYYY'))
    PARTITION year_after VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
    );
```

What i couldn't find is if there is a way to add also indexes in the subpartitions.

Currently i have an index on the **date** column (which i want to remove) but not on the state partitions.

Brief, is there a way to create an index on a subpartition ?

Comment: Sounds like you need a local index on the state column. That way the index's partitions and subpartitions would correspond to those of the table's.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is rather uncommon to create index partition different to partitions of table.

Usually you create either a global index

```
create index SOME_INDEX_NAME on sample_regional_sales (txn_date) global;
```

or you make local index:

```
create index SOME_INDEX_NAME on sample_regional_sales (txn_date) local;
```

By this every table (sub-)partition gets automatically a corresponding index partition.

When you create the index as you did

```
create index SOME_INDEX_NAME on sample_regional_sales (txn_date) global
    PARTITION by range (txn_date)
    (
    PARTITION q1_1999 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-APR-1999','DD-MON-YYYY')),
    ...
    );
```

the index is created in sub-partition. A partition is just a set of subpartitions.

Statement "Currently I have an index on the state column but not on the state partitions." does not make any sense. You define an index on a column for entire table. This index can be divided (i.e. partitionized) in several physical parts.

Comment: Corrected the statement "Currently I have an index on the state column but not on the state partitions."  . I meant that i have an index in the date but not on the state.

Comment: When you remove the index from txn_date then you remove the index - period. What is your intention? Or do you like to remove it only from certain (sub)partitions but not all?

Comment: My goal is to have txn_date of the each range partition indexed but also state column from each list partition . Maybe i am going in the wrong direction . I just tried with your suggestion using a local index on each column separately but the cost in the explain plan was exactly the same as with the global index. Also the query resulted in exact the same time.

Comment: How does your query look like?

Comment: Again, when you create an index you always define it for **entire** table (let's skip option [Partial Indexes for Partitioned Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-256BA7EE-BF49-42DE-9B38-CD2480A73129.htm#VLDBG14102) for clarity). "Partition" just means you cut the index (or the table) into multiple physical chucks - which are basically all equal. You cannot say "I like to define an index on a partition or subpartition"

Comment: i have added my query here: http://paste.ofcode.org/jcnp5kZVpJDNrGsBp9kk6e

I have partitioned the TEMP_RESULT_GROUP by range for the TEMP_TIMESTAMP field and created list subpartition for the CODE field. 

Currently my sql cost of this count is above 50.000 in the explain plan. Actually this is my bottleneck in my application since some queries require more than 1 minute to be executed.

Comment: Please edit your question with query incl. explain plan accordingly instead of using external pages for code. Anyway, the problem seems to be `TRUNC(tempresult0_.TEMP_TIMESTAMP) < ...`. When you use a function (`TRUNC` in your case) then Oracle cannot use the index, unless you use function based index. Then why do you make `UPPER()` on a number value?

Comment: 1) The "code" is a varchar . Also my index is functional with UPPER() . Same happens with my timestamp column. My index is functional again. But i can check if Hibernate is indeed passing the appropriate variable. But even without the timestamp in my where clause, the query count query execution takes 60+ seconds to execute and the cost is still way too high. I understand that my main problem is the the full table scan that is performed during the count on the TEMP_RESULT_GROUP table but i cannot overcome this issue.

Comment: Then put your real problem into question, not your non-working solution guess.